# Shared hosting (just host) and ftp access

Tags: permissions, ftp, shared-hosting, isolated-network

I have a shared hosting account with justhost, what i need is to give an FTP access to a site operator, to his website.
The website is a sub-folder under the www folder.
I know how to limit his FTP access to the folder only, but i need a way to isolate the files that he will upload as well, to prevent a script from accessing the parent folders ETC.

is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you get that client their own shared hosting account? Sure, it'll cost a couple bucks a month, but that's well worth it to protect your stuff.

Comment: You are correct, but it's not a client, it's an operator of a single site, on a shared account - owned by the client..

Answer (score 1):

As often, it depends...

You can't really prevent the site operator from uploading badly written scripts or even malicious scripts unless you create something like a staging area and have somebody do a code revision before publication on the webserver itself.

Since often that's not feasable, you can configure your webserver to be very restrictive with the content in that website, effectively you'll only allow static content:

- disbale .htaccess overrides
- disable script handlers i.e. php scripts won't run and the code is displayed instead of executed.
- etc.

Comment: thanks, but the thing is that they operate a wordpress site and can change the theme. meaning, php files...

Comment: I figured as much. Not running PHP as an apache module but as as a fast_cgi executable and suexec under a seperate UID can work pretty secure as well.